# How to create an ordered list with pugjs and prismic

Tags: javascript, html, pug, prismic.io

I am using Express, PugJs, and Prismic.io (headless CMS) to create a blog article.

Prismic end-point returns a JSON body with "type" for each part of the article, i.e. it could be a paragraph, an image, a header, or a list.

I then use pugjs to case statement to handle each type the following way:

```
            div(class='article-body')
            - let ul_list = false
            - let ol_list = false
            each item in document.ik_article_content
                case item.type
                    when 'paragraph'
                        - ol_list = false
                        - ul_list = false
                        p #{item.text}
                    when 'heading1'
                        h1 #{item.text}
                    when 'heading2'
                        h2 #{item.text}
                    when 'heading3'
                        h3 #{item.text}
                    when 'heading4'
                        h4 #{item.text}
                    when 'image'
                        img(class='article-body__image' src=`${item.url}`)
                    when 'hyperlink'
                        a(href=`${item.text}`) 
                    when 'o-list-item'
                        if !ol_list 
                            - ol_list = true
                            ol
                                li #{item.text}
                        else
                            li #{item.text}
                    when 'list-item'
                        if !ul_list 
                            - ul_list = true
                            ul
                                li #{item.text}
                        else
                    default 
                        p #{item.text}
```

Prismic returns to types: 'o-list-item' (ordered list) and 'list-item' (unordered list).

I need to interpret these types in order to create the opening and closing  or  tags.

The problem is that I am unsure how to do that especially with pugjs which auto closes tags.

In the code above I tried to create a variable which indicates that a list has started, and then I try to set that variable to false if a list has ended. But that doesn't work.

How else could I handle dynamically create ordered and unordered lists with pugjs?

Thank you.

Comment: Whoever voted to close this question, it should not be closed. It has sufficient details and is sufficiently clear.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to re-implement a function to parse Prismic API rich text fields. Thankfully we got you covered with [Prismic DOM](https://github.com/prismicio/prismic-dom#usage) which is a library that provides you a utility to parse those fields, handling lots of edge cases on your behalf (like getting the `span` key right and applying inline style: em, strong, etc.)

You should check out the doc about how to use it here: https://prismic.io/docs/nodejs/templating/rich-text (there's a `pug` switch on examples) and if you prefer to see code we have an example blog using it running on Express and Pug just like you here: https://github.com/prismicio/nodejs-blog see [how we injected Prismic DOM](https://github.com/prismicio/nodejs-blog/blob/master/app.js#L24-L28) and [usage in pug files](https://github.com/prismicio/nodejs-blog/blob/master/views/bloghome.pug#L11).

Let us know how it goes or hit me up if I didn't get your issue right :)

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely an interesting puzzle. I would recommend transforming the `document.ik_article_content` array into something more manageable before trying to go straight into templating. You could do that with an inline code block in Pug, like below. In this approach, I swap out the Prismic `type` values for the actual HTML tags to make things easier later on.

See if this works for you:

```
-
  // prismic to tag dictionary
  let prismicToTag = {
    'heading1':    'h1',
    'heading2':    'h2',
    'heading3':    'h3',
    'heading4':    'h4',
    'heading5':    'h5',
    'heading6':    'h6',
    'paragraph':   'p',
    'image':       'img',
    'hyperlink':   'a',
    'list-item':   'ul',
    'o-list-item': 'ol'
  }

  // declare variables
  const content = document.ik_article_content
  let pugReadyContent = []
  let lastType = null

  // for each element
  content.forEach(function(element) {
    // swap the prismic type string for the pug tag
    element.type = prismicToTag[element.type]
    // if the element is not a list item
    if (element.type !== 'ol' && element.type !== 'ul') {
      // append it to the new array
      pugReadyContent.push(element)
    }
    // if the element is a list item
    else {
      // if it's the first item in the list
      if (element.type !== lastType) {
        // append a new list element to the new array, with the item as a child
        pugReadyContent.push({
          type: element.type,
          children: [element]
        })
      }
      // if it's not the first item in the list
      else {
        // append it as a child to the last item in the new array
        pugReadyContent[pugReadyContent.length - 1].children.push(element)
      }
    }
    // set the lastType variable
    lastType = element.type
  })

// the templating
each item in pugReadyContent
  if (item.type !== 'ol' && item.type !== 'ul')
    if (item.type === 'img')
      img.article-body__image(src= item.url)
    else if (item.type === 'a')
      a(href= item.url) #{item.text}
    else
      #{item.type} #{item.text}
  else
    #{item.type}
      each listItem in item.children
        li #{listItem.text}
```